# css : setting all the elements of nav in the same row

Tags: html, css

I have a problem for setting all the elements of the `header` in the same row.
Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default header navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="col-md-12 nav-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="opener-left-menu is-open">
                                    <span class="top"></span> <span class="middle"></span> <span class="bottom"></span>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> <b>Consultation Web</b></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right user-nav">
                                <li class="user-name"><span>User name</span></li>
                                <li class="dropdown avatar-dropdown">
                                    <img src="./app/shared/img/avatar.jpg"
                                        class="img-circle avatar" alt="user name" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                        aria-expanded="true" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

I have tried to surround the elements in a `row` class.
also i gave `class="col-md-3"` for both elements. So, I expect that i use only half the available columns.  **Unfortunately, the** `img` **tag always go to the next row.**  I want to have all the element in only one row.
How can i fix it?

Here is the css i am using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app/shared/css/style.css">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
```

I am sure that, `style.css` is get loaded properly.

Comment: Did you try to increase the size of the navbar-right? Probably there isn't enough Space in 3/12 columns.

Comment: Have you added `bootstrap.min.css` , `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` in your `<head>` tag?

Comment: put `nav` in a `row` too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
I forgot to add the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```